# What should be the word vectors of token <pad>, <unknown>, <go>, <EOS> before sent into RNN?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

In word embedding, what should be a good vector representation for the start_tokens _PAD, _UNKNOWN, _GO, _EOS?

Comment: Very vague question. Input vectors and the target vectors are both derived from a collection of texts. RNNs then learn weights for hidden layers that represent *appear* to represent relationships among words and texts.

The input vectors for RNNs are usually either word-document co-occurrence matrix weighted by [TF*IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) or a word-word co-occurrence matrix (neighbors).

Comment: What should be vectors if you have pretrained word2vec model from google and you don't want to train embeddings again. Should it be just vector of zeros or ones or something different?

Answer (score 7):

Spettekaka's answer works if you are updating your word embedding vectors as well.

Sometimes you will want to use pretrained word vectors that you can't update, though. In this case, you can add a new dimension to your word vectors for each token you want to add and set the vector for each token to 1 in the new dimension and 0 for every other dimension. That way, you won't run into a situation where e.g. "EOS" is closer to the vector embedding of "start" than it is to the vector embedding of "end".

Example for clarification:

```
# assume_vector embeddings is a dictionary and word embeddings are 3-d before adding tokens
# e.g. vector_embedding['NLP'] = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4]) 

vector_embedding['<EOS>'] = np.array([0,0,0,1])
vector_embedding['<PAD>'] = np.array([0,0,0,0,1])
new_vector_length = vector_embedding['<pad>'].shape[0] # length of longest vector
for key, word_vector in vector_embedding.items():
    zero_append_length = new_vector_length - word_vector.shape[0]
    vector_embedding[key] = np.append(word_vector, np.zeros(zero_append_length))
```

Now your dictionary of word embeddings contains 2 new dimensions for your tokens and all of your words have been updated.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Do you know if this is how it is done in most popular embeddings?

Comment: I don't know about the popularity of this, but this method has worked for me in in the past when creating a seq-2-seq model.

Comment: Did you come up with this idea yourself?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you can represent these tokens by any vector.

Here's why:

Inputting a sequence of words to your model, you first convert each word to an ID and then look in your embedding-matrix which vector corresponds to that ID. With that vector, you train your model. But the embedding-matrix just contains also trainable weights which will be adjusted during training. The vector-representations from your pretrained vectors just serve as a good point to start to yield good results.

Thus, it doesn't matter that much what your special tokens are represented by *in the beginning* as their representation will change during training.

Comment: It is common to use word2vec features as frozen embeddings that don't need further training to minimize training time. You can, of course, but you often don't when the embeddings are just part of a much larger whole.